# Como organizar links ao redor do centro com flexbox

Tags: html, css

Olá, consegui centralizar meu **logo** e colocar os links ao redor, o problema e que o logo sobrepoe os links, queria que ficasse alinhado e diminuise a margem entre cada link.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
   /* font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; */
}
.logomobile{
    display: none;
}
.topdois{
    float: right;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: wheat;
}
.socialIcon{display: none;}
i span{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.topdois ul li i{
    color: #fff;
}
.topdois ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-size: 17px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: -10px;
}
.topdois ul li:nth-child(5){
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}

.topdois ul li:hover{
    background-color: orchid;
    transition: .3s;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  }
  .topdois ul li i {
    margin: 0 15px;
  }
#menu{
    display: none;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/jItSH6a.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: darken;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

nav {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/26/06/01/pattern-3107886__340.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: fixed bottom center;
width: 100%;
height: 115px;
}
nav .logo {
    line-height: 55px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.7;
    top: 60px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 300;
}
nav ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    top: 53px;
}

nav ul li {
    font-family: "Cabin", serif;
list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bolder;

}

nav ul li a {
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}


nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color: chartreuse;
    transition: .3s;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  }

nav>label span {
    font-family: "Roboto", serif;
    color: #fff;
}

nav>label span {
    font-family: "Roboto", serif;
}

input {
    display: none;
}

nav ul label {
    display: none;
}

nav label {
    cursor: pointer;
}


@media (max-width:768px) {
    .logomobile img{
        width: 280px;
        height: 70px;
        margin-top: 13px;
       margin-left: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        display: block;
    
    }
    .logomobile{
        display: block;
    }
    .socialIcon {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .socialIcon ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
.socialIcon a i{
    margin-top: 4px;
}
    .socialIcon a {
        color: #fff;
        height: 42px;
        width: 42px;
        background-color: teal;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 33px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 35px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        margin-right: 14px;
    }

    .socialIcon a:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .logo {
        margin-left: 20px;
        position: relative;
        width: 170px;
        height: 67px;
        top: 20px;
    }
    .topdois{
display: none;
    }
    #menu{
        display: block;
    }
    nav{
        height: 65px;
    }
    nav ul {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        left: -100%;
        padding-top: 100px;
        /*background-color: darkred; */
        background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/25/18/06/color-2174065__340.pnga);
        transition: 0.8s ease;
        box-shadow: 8px -8px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    
   
    nav ul li a{
        color: #fff;
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: 18px;
    
    }
    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        padding: 11px;
        width: 95%;
        background-color: darkred;
        margin-left: 10px;
        border-top: 2px solid rgb(255,255,255, 0.3);
        transition: 0.5s ease;
    }
    
nav ul li:nth-child(2){
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}


    nav>label {
        display: flex;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    nav ul label {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        right: -47px;
        font-size: 51px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    input:checked~ul {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="topdois">        
        <ul>
        <li><a href=".ss"> <i class="fa fa-home"><span>Lista</span></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=".ss"> <i class="fa fa-home"><span>Lista</span></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=".ss"> <i class="fa fa-home"><span>Lista</span></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=".ss"> <i class="fa fa-home"><span>Lista</span></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=".ss"> <i class="fa fa-home"><span>Lista</span></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="box">
        <label for="box">
          <div id="menu">  <span><i class="fas fa-bars" style="font-size:34px"></i></span></div>
        </label>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7qGd4cE.png" alt="" class="logo">
        <ul>
            <label for="box">
                <span><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
            </label>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">A Teste</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nossos Produtos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receitas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            <div class="logomobile">
                <img src="https://www.novitrine.com.br/images/noticia/A55720da696c81.jpga" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="socialIcon">
                <a href="jsls.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="jsls.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
                <a href="jsls.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="jsls.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-google"></i></a>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara esse estrutura do seu Menu está bem estranha, isso vai te dar muito trabalho para arrumar, aproveita que está no início e reflita se não é melhor recomeçar.... Um dica que já vou te dar de cara, os filhos DIRETO de um UL, devem ser apenas LI, vc não pode ter Span, Label, ou Div, como sendo filho direto de uma UL. Sobre o Alinhamento pesquise sobre display:flex e justify-content: space-between, isso vai te ajudar

Comment: @hugocsl mano usei space-between, e flex na nav que é o pai,vou ver essa dica de remover o label, poderia tentar da uma olhada pra mim? to tentando aqui não achei a solução ainda, poderia da uma olhada no pen??

Comment: pode usar o z-index do css para definir qual elemento fica na frente.